# approve + safeTransferFrom ERC721 from existing smart contract

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, erc-721, nft

I am trying to call ERC721 from another smart contract, while calling function **approveAndTransfer** ,I am getting "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved", not sure reason behind it,

As **require(nft.ownerOf(_tokenId) == msg.sender, "NOT OWNER");** is working as expected and not throwing any error,  but source of error is **_tranfer** function which gets called from
**nft.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, _to,_tokenId);**

not sure what mistake I am making.
I have NFT in my wallet, but I am not owner of external smart contract.

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Receiver.sol";

contract Tat is IERC721Receiver {
    
constructor() public {}


function approveAndTransfer(IERC721 nft, uint256 _tokenId, address _from, address _to) public {
    require(nft.ownerOf(_tokenId) == msg.sender, "NOT OWNER");
    nft.isApprovedForAll(_from, address(this));
    nft.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, _to,_tokenId);
}

function ownerOf(IERC721 nft, uint256 tokenId) external view returns (address owner) {
    return nft.ownerOf(tokenId);
}


function test() public view returns(address sc,address own){
    return (address(this),msg.sender);
}


function onERC721Received(address _operator, address _from, uint256 _tokenId, bytes memory _data) public override returns(bytes4) {
       return 0x150b7a02;
 }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you get error like "This contract may be abstract, not implement an abstract parent's methods completely or not invoke an inherited contract's constructor correctly."?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like one of your function calls needs to be changed -let's look at the `approveAndTransfer` function from your contract:

```
function approveAndTransfer(IERC721 nft, uint256 _tokenId, address _from, address _to) public {
    require(nft.ownerOf(_tokenId) == msg.sender, "NOT OWNER");
    nft.isApprovedForAll(_from, address(this));
    nft.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, _to,_tokenId);
}
```

It looks like the goal of the function is to transfer NFTs from the `_from` address to the `_to` address. In order to do so, the flow needs to be:

- approve the contract to send `_from`'s NFT
- contract sends to `_to`

After the `require`, though, the contract calls `isApprovedForAll` on the NFT contract. Looking at OpenZeppelin's ERC721 [docs](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/token/erc721#IERC721-isApprovedForAll-address-address-), we can see that this only tells us *if* an address is approved for another address's NFTs - it doesn't actually do the approving.

It looks like you probably wanted [`setApprovalForAll`](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/token/erc721#IERC721-setApprovalForAll-address-bool-), but if we've gotten this far in the conversation, it's worth pointing out why this is probably not the right choice for you either.

Firstly, `setApprovalForAll` would approve the contract on **all** of `_from`'s NFTs on this contract, even though the presence of a single `_tokenId` in the args indicates that the function will only transfer one NFT at a time. It isn't desirable to over-approve like that. Instead, you'd probably have wanted to use the [`approve`](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/token/erc721#IERC721-approve-address-uint256-) function, which takes a tokenId.

Secondly, and maybe this should have even been first, is that you can't approve yourself on someone else's assets. Or, in this case, the contract can't approve itself over `msg.sender`'s NFT. The reasoning is simple - if I could `approve` myself over someone else's NFTs, then I could just do that and take them whenever I wanted for no reason (also known as stealing). This is why getting a user to approve happens outside of smart contracts in any scenario that I'm aware of - you can use JavaScript to prompt a user to approve, but you can't have a smart contract approve for them.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for help, approve from web3 and transfer from smart contract worked.