# How to send the ERC721 NFT token of existing smart contract to another wallet using my smart contract

Tags: solidity, remix-tests

I have some ERC721 NFTs in my wallet minted in A smart contract.
I want to transfer that NFTs to another wallet using my smart contract.
But I am getting error  like: "ERC721: approve caller is not owner nor approved for all"

This is my code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Coller is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {

    address public  deadAddress = 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD;
    constructor(
        
    ) ERC721("Coller Token", "Coller") {

    }
 
    function approveAndTransfer(ERC721 nft, uint256 _tokenId) public {
        nft.approve(deadAddress, _tokenId);
        nft.transferFrom(msg.sender, deadAddress,_tokenId);
    }
}
```

Who can fix this error and help me?

Comment: you cant approve and transferFrom in the same transaction. In your method -> the first line will approve the deadAddress to transfer tokenId onbehalf your **contract** . The Second line is trying to transfer the token from msg.sender to deadAddress and is triggered by the contract which has no permission to do that

Comment: the msg.sender need to approve the token to the contract. and then your method need only to call transferfrom

Comment: Dear Majd, 
I didn't understand what you say.
so I hope that you send some code for me.

Comment: "I have some ERC721 NFTs in my wallet minted in **A** smart contract." ? who developed that smart contract and how you got the NFT?             
//// //// /////"I want to transfer that NFT to another wallet using **my** smart contract." ? why using **your** contract, and not just transfer the NFT using the original contract?

Comment: I minted that NFT in A smart contract and got it.
currently, I got some idea.
But to complete the idea, I have to transfer my NFT to another wallet using my smart contract.
Can you help me?
I think you are expert smart contract developer, but I am a beginner.
So if you can help me, please share the code to complete my idea.

Comment: Dear Majd, can you help me?

Comment: I'm very sorry, I can't help you. it is not that easy with solidity.. it is not coded that you can copy and run.  what I can tell you is: you can't approve and transfer in the same function(same transaction)

Comment: Dear Majd, did you see this:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98692/approve-safetransferfrom-erc721-from-existing-smart-contract

Comment: Yes and I see the comments **Thanks for help, approve from web3(wallet) and transfer from smart contract worked**. so as I said you need **2 transactions** -> The first transaction will be called from outside the contract using your wallet how own the token to approve the token to the contract (you need to call the method "approve(<contract-address>, <tokenId>)". And then you can remove "nft.approve(deadAddress, _tokenId);" from your method and call it to transfer the token. (no idea if there are any security risks cause I don't have enough information)