# Is it possible to call a ERC721 transfer function when you are not the Owner?

Tags: solidity, web3js, erc-721, ethers.js

Is it possible to call a ERC721 transfer function when you are not the Owner? Am pretty new to solidity so if you can plz provide your code so I can understand well. (BTW had asked question before but I was a bit confuse by he/her answer) here my code again:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract Tink is ERC721 {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;

    constructor() ERC721("Tink", "TNT") { 

    }

    function _baseURI() internal pure override returns (string memory) {
        return "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmX8ih22uNW5cDH5CeorzpTHTbsioFurgD6w5q7RKt298H";
    }


    function mint(address to)
        public returns (uint256)
    {
        require(_tokenIdCounter.current() < 3); 
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        _safeMint(to, _tokenIdCounter.current());

        return _tokenIdCounter.current();
    }
}
```

Comment: ERC721 has no "transfer" function. it has "TransferFrom(sender, receiver, tokenId)"
if you are using the openzeppelin contracts (without any change) then only the owner or approver can transfer the tokens. if someone else tries then it will revert. 
btw, in your contract everyone can call mint(..)

Comment: @MajdTL  but if anyone can call the mint function how will they send ether to my account?

Comment: they don't need to send you ether, that is not in your code! you are just limiting the number of nfts to total of 3 and they will just call the mint function. Anyway, the question is not about mint. It is about transfer and only the owner and approver can call transfer (it is the expected behavior) unless you change the code

Comment: @MajdTL Then how do call a transferFrom function without being the owner?

Comment: I need to understand why you want to call transferFrom without being the owner of the Id?

Comment: @MajdTL ok when people/buyers click on the buy button in my website they it will transfer the ERC-721/NFT to there from my account (Its pretty hard to explain) using Moralis ERC-721.

Comment: First: you need to restrict the mint function for only yourself. otherwise, they can mint it directly. 
Second: idk how Moralis exactly do it? are you giving the skd your private key that own the tokens?

as Far I know Moralis supports Testnets, so try it on testnet. it is really easier if you start learning with something simpler as ERC721 :)

Comment: @MajdTL how do I restrict it for my self?

Comment: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/access-control#ownership-and-ownable check this, any try to learn with simple contracts first

Comment: @MajdTL but its for ERC20 contracts

Comment: it is an extension that works on every contract and method. don't want to be rude but you are still new in solidity and need to learn those things by yourself first and the chat here is not the right place to learn solidity. you can ask questions if you have a problem and you will get a hint for the solution, no one will come and write you the code or tell you what exactly to do.. it is risky and no one will do it

Comment: @MajTL my bad :/

Comment: @MajTL Just wondering once I have restricted the mint function to make me to be the only person that can call this function  what do I do next ? BTW am still reading the doc rn

Answer (score 1):

Yes, anybody can call the transfer functions (`transferFrom` and both flavors of `safeTransferFrom`). But typically the functions will throw if they are not authorized.

Here are the scenarios which typically will result in a successful transfer:

1. Owner of the token is calling the transfer
2. That specific token is approved to somebody else that is transferring
3. Owner of the token does "authorize for all" to somebody else that is transferring
4. Contract has "backdoored" other accessors for tokens

Comment: How do I authorize my contract for Anyone that call the transfer function? thanks in advance.

Comment: You are able to customize the `transferFrom` and `safeTransferFrom` functions to add your own authentication.

Comment: How? more specifically

Comment: By creating an overriding function. Anything more specific than that, of course, requires details about the application's requirements

Comment: So your saying that I have to override my function? also I read another question here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98692/approve-safetransferfrom-erc721-from-existing-smart-contract you have to approve from outside of the contract like web3 right? (btw if you can plz provide code as explanation)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, literally everybody can call any function in your contract. To restrict this behaviour, you should make the contract Ownable.

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/ownership

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).