# How do I call a ERC721 safeTransferFrom function and approve the caller in web3?

Tags: web3js, javascript, ethereumjs, ethers.js

how do I call safeTransferFrom function and approve the caller in web3 also without using node.js,
Provide code as explanation.

Comment: This is a similar question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98692/approve-safetransferfrom-erc721-from-existing-smart-contract